# Flink issues with getting data from cassandra to use as dataset

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink

I am trying to pull in data from a cassandra table to use as a dataset, but have two issues that I have come across.

The first is that cassandraInputFormat only returns a tuple, and I'd prefer to not have a tuple12 and just use a pojo to define what it will expect back. So I don't know if this is just something I will have to accept, if there is a way to use a pojo instead like with the cassandraConnector (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/cassandra.html), or if using the cassandraInputFormat is not the best way to go about getting the data.

The other issue is even with the data I pull I get from the cassandraInputFormat (be it tuple or not) I don't know the way to set it as the data source. For files, csv and HDFS there is plenty of methods (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment.html#ExecutionEnvironment--) but none that are explicitly for cassandra. So my guess is that I would need to pull the data using the cassandraInputFormat and use something like .fromElements() or .fromCollecton() and what the proper way to do that is.

Thanks for any help in advance!

UPDATE:

This "works" (and thanks to Chesnay Schepler for the help):

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, String>> testSet = 
exEnv.createInput(cassandraInputFormat, TypeInformation.of(newTypeHint<Tuple2<String, String>>(){}));
```

But this error is occurring now...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.optimizer.CompilerException: 
Error translating node 'Data Source "at execute(CodeBatchProcessorImpl.java:85) 
(org.apache.flink.batch.connectors.cassandra.CassandraInputFormat)" : NONE 
[[ GlobalProperties [partitioning=RANDOM_PARTITIONED] ]] [[ LocalProperties [ordering=null, grouped=null, unique=null] ]]':
Could not write the user code wrapper class org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.util.UserCodeObjectWrapper :
java.io.NotSerializableException: flink.streaming.code.CodeBatchProcessorImpl
```

And further down it includes:

`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment`

UPDATE 2:

Had to set environment to transient. Fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CassandraInputFormat, and all InputFormats for that matter, by calling ExecutionEnvironment#createInput(InputFormat).

There is currently no option to directly read elements as POJOs. The easiest workaround is to add a MapFunction after the sink that converts the Tuples into your desired POJO.

Comment: I tried "DataSet<Tuple2<String, String>> testSet = exEnv.createInput(cassandraInputFormat);" but it comes back with the error:

"org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The type returned by the input format could not be automatically determined. Please specify the TypeInformation of the produced type explicitly by using the 'createInput(InputFormat, TypeInformation)' method instead". Any ideas on how to fix? I tried add Tuple2<String, String> and a bunch of other ways but nothing is correct appearently.

Comment: Figured out what I had to do to solve the error. This works: DataSet<Tuple2<String, String>> testSet = exEnv.createInput(cassandraInputFormat, TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<String, String>>(){}));

Comment: ah yes, you have to explicitly define the output type, the reason being that the InputFormat itself has no information whatsoever as to what it will emit, while the job is being created.